# jpa createQuery select column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to make query for specific column

I tried this. and this one worked.

```
List<ProductInfo> productInfo = em.createQuery( "select m from ProductInfo AS m", ProductInfo.class).getResultList();
```

But below were not working.

```
List<ProductInfo> productInfo = em.createQuery( "select m.model from ProductInfo AS m", ProductInfo.class).getResultList();     

//or
List<ProductInfo> productInfo = em.createQuery( "select model from ProductInfo AS m", ProductInfo.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: it's not working because entityManager expects that the execution result can be mapped to a passed class, i.e. ProductInfo.class. in the first case you fetch the whole object, so it works, but in the other cases you're trying to fetch one field, that can't be mapped to an object of the provided class

Answer (score 1):

Since your query is specific to a column, it will return a list of Object, which contains all your column results

```
List<Object> productInfo = em.createQuery( "select m.model from ProductInfo AS m", Object.class).getResultList();
```

or to retrieve results as list of `ProductInfo`

```
TypedQuery<ProductInfo> typedQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW <package-name>.ProductInfo(m.model) from ProductInfo AS m", ProductInfo.class);    
List<ProductInfo> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used TypedQuery and Query for solving the problems.